# Difference between these three sextuplets notation

Tags: theory, notation

Could anybody please explain the difference in how to play the lower voices in the following examples, and how they would be played timing-wise, between these three ways of writing a sextuplet? The only thing I know about them is that all six notes should be played during a single beat.

**Note**: for the third example I could not remember where I saw it so I just modified the first one since I though that would be simpler than trying to describe it.

[image: Two examples]
[image: Third example]

Comment: They aren't meant to be played differently. Are you asking about the sextuplet timing or the actual notes or fingering on the guitar?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - The timing.

Comment: The timing is the same for all three examples. As far as I can tell, the notation for the first two examples is identical. What are you seeing as the difference between them?

Comment: @ToddWilcox -  Then what's the point of writing the triplet on the down stems and marking only the first one as an 8th note?

Comment: Oh! I thought you were asking about the sextuplet voice, not the lower voices.

Comment: Try playing just the 8th and quarter notes in the first two examples and the difference should be clear. In the first example, the 16th notes are divided into groups of three, while in the second they are divided into groups of two. There isn't any hard and fast rule of notation that says so, but that's how they relate to the longer notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can count the **beat** 1-2-3-4, but it will be much easier to count the sub-beats as this  same  pattern is  repeated  4 times in one measure)

**1**-2-3-**4**-5-6 (4 x 6 sextuplets in one measure, some count the first of the sextuplets numbering the 4/4th notes:

- **1**-2-3-4-5-6, **2**-2-3-4-5-6, **3**-2-3-4-5-6, *4**-2-3-4-5-6
- or you could even count twice to 3 for one sextuplets **1**-2-3-**1**-2-3  twice 3 triplets for a pattern of one **beat** (4 times in one measure!)

in any case it is the sub-beats that you must have in your mind and that you can feel in your fingers and that you can hear as rhythm pattern!

If you read and play in the way described above, the lower notes will have to be played exactly on that single sextuplet note where it is written:

**1st and 3rd example**: if you count just **1**-2-3-**1**-2-3 the lower note will always be placed together with **1**

in the 2nd example it will come together with **1** and **3** and the second note will be hold along the last sextuplet notes: **1**-2-**3**-4-5-6

Answer (score 4):

The lower voice in the first and third examples are played exactly the same. You hold each of the lowest notes of the arpeggio for half of the length of the sextuplet.

For the middle example, you hold the first low voice note for the first third of the sextuplet and then the second low voice note you hold for the remaining two thirds of the sextuplet.

Comment: That's correct- the first&third are straight eighth-notes.   The second is clearly marked as a triplet.